# ShareLaTeX and auto-pst-pdf

Tags: sharelatex, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

In my code I'm using `chemnum` to number chemical compounds on ShareLaTeX. Since now I was compiling setting `latex` as compiler, but, for a list of reasons, I would like to switch to `pdflatex`. So I added the line

```
\usepackage[run=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

and switched the compiler to `pdflatex`, but the compilation failed, because `auto-pst-pdf` couldn't create `output-pics.pdf`. The complete log is [here](http://pastebin.com/Z2efxpaD).

If I compile the same code locally on my machine with `pdflatex`, the compilation ends with no errors. [Here](http://pastebin.com/U1EdsU43) you can find the log of my local successful compilation.

Thinking about an issue with the ShareLaTeX compiler, I wrote to the ShareLaTeX support team, but they replied saying they are "not able to help with in-depth LaTeX questions" and recommended "asking this question on tex.stackexchange.com". So I'm here! :D

Here is my MWE: you can find the file `ammide.eps` [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01164559016355390825).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[run=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage{chemnum}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname={Elenco degli Schemi},
name=Schema,
placement=htbp,
]{scheme}

\begin{document}
    \begin{scheme}[htbp]
        \replacecmpd{tiofencarbossilato}
        \replacecmpd{cloruroacido}
        \replacecmpd{ammide}
        \includegraphics{ammide.eps}
        \caption{Sintesi N,N-dietiltiofen-3-carbossiammide}
    \end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

An even-more-minimal working example is simply

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[run=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

which, on ShareLaTeX using `pdflatex`, produces the output file correctly, but still has the warning `Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: Could not create output-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted. This warning occured on input line 124.` which, in the end, is the main problem I'm addressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surprising thing in your log-file is that your sharelatex seems to use texlive 2015 (I still see TL2014), and that it seems to activate --shell-escape.

The source of the problem is that sharelatex sets `\jobname` to "output" and this confuses auto-pst-pdf. E.g. it tries to run `latex output.tex`. You can reproduce the problem locally by running `pdflatex --jobname=output --shell-escape yourfile`.

You could try to redefine `\jobname` in the document. But it is possible that this confuses other packages, so I would advise to use it in small documents to create the pictures which you then include normally in your main document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\def\jobname{test-utf8} %<-- your file name
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[run=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname={Elenco degli Schemi},
name=Schema,
placement=htbp,
]{scheme}

\begin{document}
    \begin{scheme}[htbp]
        \replacecmpd{tiofencarbossilato}
        \replacecmpd{cloruroacido}
        \replacecmpd{ammide}
        \includegraphics{ammide.eps}
        \caption{Sintesi N,N-dietiltiofen-3-carbossiammide}
    \end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I simply added that line to my main document as you suggested and everything compiles perfectly now! No other package has been confused as you feared.

Comment: A biibliography and an index maybe a problem.

Comment: My document has a (manual) bibliography and a `\tableofcontents`, but I've had no problems so far with `\def\jobname{main}` on ShareLaTeX.